# Is the C++ Standard Library replaceable?

Tags: c++

Is the C++ standard library tied to the compiler or can a different implementation be provided?

I wonder about this mostly because it seems that the relation between the `typeid` keyword and `std::type_info` hinders this. The `typeid` keywords depends on the existence of `std::type_info`, which I would consider to be a dependency in the wrong direction. And I have no idea how a custom implementation should implement the `type_info::name()` method.

My questions are:

- Is the standard library replaceable?
- If yes, then how does one implement `std::type_info`

Comment: Note to answerers: STL != Standard Library. The STL is merely a part of the standard library. The STL is replacable with merely a library. The standard library is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Large parts of the library are independent of the compiler, like containers and algorithms.

Other parts are very much tied to a specific compiler, like you have found - `type_info` where the library rather documents what the compiler does rather than prescribes it.

Other similar examples might be bad_exception, std::size_t, and C++11 features like type_traits, atomics, and std::initializer_list, which all need support from the compiler. The library has to be closely matched to what a specific compiler actually does.

It is possible to write a library that works with several compilers, but not without tuning some low level code to each specific compiler. The libraries mentioned elsewhere does exactly that.

Answer (score 12):

Yep, there are a variety of 'STLs':

- Original STL implementation by Stepanov and Lee. 1994, Hewlett-Packard. No longer maintained.
- SGI STL, based on original implementation by Stepanov & Lee. 1997, Silicon Graphics. No longer maintained.
- libstdc++ from gnu (was part of libg++)
- libc++ from clang
- STLPort, based on SGI STL
- Rogue Wave standard library (HP, SGI, SunSoft, Siemens-Nixdorf)
- Dinkum STL library by P.J. Plauger

Edit:

Since this apparently is about the **C++ Standard Library**, there are some alternatives to that too:

- Apache C++ Standard Library (http://stdcxx.apache.org/)
- Dinkumware C++ Standard Library (http://www.dinkumware.com/cpp.aspx)
- libc++ C++ Standard Library (http://libcxx.llvm.org/)
- GNU's libstdc++

Comment: @Naszta - That is based on the Dinkumware library.

Comment: @Naszta No it doesn't, VS uses the Dinkumware library with VS specific stuff added in.

Comment: As I understand it, STL Port is no longer being maintained. Also, this doesn't answer the question about compiler-centric classes like `type_info` or in C++0x `initializer_list`. Do those get replaced?

Comment: @0A0D: Their [list of supported compilers](http://www.stlport.org/doc/platforms.html) says otherwise. They don't support any version of Visual Studio 2002 and above, and they don't support any version of GCC past 3.0. They haven't had a release since 2008, and the [statistics for the last 12 months](http://sourceforge.net/project/stats/detail.php?group_id=146814&ugn=stlport&type=git&mode=12months) on their SourceForge account seems to be read-only. This all sounds like a dead project to me.

Comment: Some types, like type_info and initializer_list, are built into the compiler and the library can just document what they are. There are other types similar to that, like size_t and ptrdiff_t, that only tell us what the compiler already knows.

Comment: -1 because this is question is about the standard library, not the STL. Most of the C++ standard library predates the STL by a large margin.

Comment: What is the library shipped with Comeau?

Comment: Another question: What do the Intel and the IBM compilers use?

Comment: Same -1 of @BillyONeal

Answer (score 8):

It is replaceable. Take a look into [stl port](http://www.stlport.org/)

Comment: I am not sure, but `std::type_info` might require compiler's support for it.

Comment: It does. STLPort has defines configuring it for each compiler it supports.

Comment: The latest release of STLport is from 2.5 years ago. Not what I'd call a thriving OSS project. Did they actually even start to address things like C++11 type traits?

Comment: @sbi No idea. http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/ shows that something was updated 1 month ago

Comment: @VJo: Yeah, I saw that. But if they don't release, checking in isn't worth anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, STL is not binded with compiler even though different compile has it's default STL implementation.
You can generally change the STL implemtation by change some Project setting.

E.g. In vS2008, you can do

Tools->Options->Project and Solutions -> VC++ Directoires -> Include fiels, add a different implementation(e.g. STL PORT), then move this line to the top(above the default implementation), then you have it.

Comment: Anyone care to add why he/she got this one a downvote ? Is it just for a typo ? If so I bet you didn't read through my answers instead you just read the first fews word...

Comment: Just a guess, but you're using "STL" and "standard library" as if they were interchangeable. Which they are not. (From what I can see, you seem to mean the right thing, but it's hard to tell with you confusing the terms.)

Answer (score 0):

One more example of an alternative STL, sacrificing some standard-compliance for speed: EASTL (by Electronic Arts) https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL